# How to access photos and videos stored inside Google Photos "Locked Folder" using adb?

Tags: adb, backup, google-photos

I would like to take the backup of all photos and videos stored inside google photo's "Locked folder".

I use adb to pull out files from my android. And i would like to seemlessly pull media from the locked folder using adb and then delete them from my phone.

Any way to do it, without moving the media out of "Locked Folder" first?

Comment: In my understanding the purpose of "locking" images is to make them only available within the app itself. As Google knows how to implements such a feature in a secure way there shouldn't be a way to access those images outside of the Photos app (may be with root, but I don't know how exactly locked images are stored).